# F#: Declare function and find element in list

Tags: math, functional-programming, f#, computer-science, f#-interactive

I'm quite new to F# and need some help with a problem. I'm having trouble finding an element in a list: 
"Declare a function findRoute: Lid*LuggageCatalogue -> Route, that finds the route for a given luggage identification in a luggage catalogue"

I have listed the different types and given the types elements.

```
    type Lid = string 
    type Flight = string
    type Airport = string
    type Route = (Flight*Airport) list
    let route = [("DL 189","ATL"); ("DL 124","BRU"); ("SN 733","CPH"); ("SK 208","ATL"); ("DL 124","BRU"); ("SK 122","JFK")]

    type LuggageCatalogue = (Lid*Route) list
    let lc = [("DL 016-914", [("DL 189","ATL"); ("DL 124","BRU"); ("SN 733","CPH")]); 
    ("SK 222-142", [("SK 208","ATL"); ("DL 124","BRU"); ("SK 122","JFK")])]


    let findRoute fr = function
    match fr with
    | [] -> printf "No match"
    |
```

Where I'm stuck is that I cannot find the correct way to use the function to find the elements in the `LuggageCatalogue` list

Comment: The problem seems to be that you haven't really written any code yet. You should try doing that and come back with a more specific problem, like a compiler error or that it's not producing the result that you expect.

Comment: Please do not remove essential parts of the question. If you're having trouble getting around some anti-plagiarism or anti-cheat tool, you really should have thought of that before doing the deed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could start by filtering the luggage catalogue to better understand what is going on, e.g.

```
let filterlist lid = List.filter (fun (luggageid, _) -> luggageid = lid)
```

Then finding a particular item in the catalogue would be something like

```
filterlist "SK 222-142" lc
```

Or even better, try to create the first part of the function yourself. Even though this is only the first step, maybe try to visualize how a recursive search function for a luggage id may look,

```
let findfirst lid =
  let rec checktail lctail =
    match lctail with
    | [] -> invalidArg "lid" "luggageid not present in catalogue"
    | (id, r)::tail -> if id = lid then r else checktail tail
  checktail lc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Really opens my eyes for the next couple of tasks.
Do you mind explain the use of "r" in the argument?

Comment: @B.O.C. Sure. That is one of the nicer F# features - pattern matching. If you write this code `let (id, r)::tail = lc` the data from `lc` is split into several 'pieces'. In this case `id` will be the string "DL 016-914", `r` will become the string list [("DL 189", "ATL"); ("DL 124", "BRU"); ("SN 733", "CPH")], and `tail` will be the rest of the `lc` luggage catalogue where the first 'item' of the catalogue (list) is discarded.